# C# Outlook Addin setCurrentFormPage throw exception

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I am developing a plugin for **outlook** with **VSTO** and i am trying to put a separate form region to show as the current form page in the open inspector but throw an exception. here is the code

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.Inspectors.NewInspector += InspectorsOnNewInspector;
        this.Application.Explorers.NewExplorer +=  Explorers_NewExplorer;
    }

    private void Explorers_NewExplorer(Outlook.Explorer explorer)
    {

    }

    private void InspectorsOnNewInspector(Outlook.Inspector inspector)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ola");
        // exception ocurrs in this line 
        inspector.SetCurrentFormPage("OutlookAddIn.RequestFormRegion");

    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to put it to work with the following code

```
 private void InspectorsOnNewInspector(Outlook.Inspector inspector)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("ola");

        if (!(inspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.TaskItem)) return;

        var taskItem = (Outlook.TaskItem) inspector.CurrentItem;

        taskItem.Open += (ref bool cancel) =>
        {
            try
            {
                inspector.SetCurrentFormPage("OutlookAddIn.RequestFormRegion");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: You might want to make taskItem a global/class variable - otherwise the Open event won't fire if the avriable gets garbage collected between the NewInspector and Open events.